# Random UIImage appearing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

Very newbie obj-c question.

In ViewController I have four UIImages. They are imitating playing cards. User can see only their backside at start. By tapping one of them user will see the front side (animation for this is ready now). My task is to show random front side from four images with defined repetition rate. So I want to set one of the images (prize) will appear eight times less Eight times less than the chance of getting any one of the others, everytime the user will visit this ViewController.

If it's possible, please show me the piece of code what can generate random but with possibility of setting repetition rate

Comment: What have you tried?  It may be easier to help you out if you can show some code, so we know what you're working with. http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Thanks for your attention, propstm! At this moment nothing, main idea is to make singleton in what I will generate random and will load UIImage from NSArray of four images, but I am not sure about how to make it at all. Sorry, I am a very newbie

Comment: Do you mean 8 times less than the other 3 combined, or 8 times less than the chance of getting any one of the others?

Comment: You need to be clearer in what you want for the selection process. Do you mean every 8 selections the prize will certainly be selected once, or for it to have the probability of it being selected 8 times less likely than the others. (Basically, for every 8 selections, a probability of 1, or 0.04^8)?

Comment: Eight times less than the chance of getting any one of the others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (NSUInteger)indexForImageGivenIndexSet:(NSIndexSet*)indexSet             // Set of indexes you want to select from
                         prizeImageIndex:(NSUInteger)prizeIndex      // The prize index
                        probabilityScale:(CGFloat)probabilityScale   // The scale for the prize (8.0 for 8x less than the others)
{
    // If invalid, return what was given
    if (![indexSet containsIndex:prizeIndex]) {
        return prizeIndex;
    }

    // Calculate our probabilities
    // For a set of 4, with a scale of 8 on the prize, our probabilities would be
    // 0.04 (prize), 0.32, 0.32, 0.32
    double prizeProbability = (1.0 / indexSet.count) * (1.0 / probabilityScale);

    double val = (double)arc4random() / RAND_MAX;

    if (val < prizeProbability) {
        return prizeIndex;
    }
    else {
        // Select from the others in range equally
        NSMutableIndexSet* newSet = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] initWithIndexSet:indexSet];
        [newSet removeIndex:prizeIndex];

        NSInteger selectedPosition = arc4random() % newSet.count;
        __block NSInteger count = 0;
        return [newSet indexPassingTest:^BOOL(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            if (count == selectedPosition) {
                *stop = YES;
                return YES;
            }
            else {
                count++;
                return NO;
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: WDUK, I don't have much background in statistics, but would you get the same result by having an array where an item representing the prize is in there once, each of the other pictures is represented 8 times, and then use array[arc4_random(25)] to  pick an item?

Comment: That would also work, but on an algorithmic point of view, isn't particularly scalable. Imagine having to pick from 250 items, with one of them having a scale of 50. You'd have an array size of 12451. Why waste so much memory for a simple probability selection task.

Comment: Thanks, I was using that more as a thought experiment than a possible coding solution. I'm not sure how to use your method -- would you pass an index set with 4 indexes and a probability scale of 8 for the OP's example? If I do that, and run the method a million times, I only get the prize index coming up about 15,600 times instead of the 40,000 that I would expect.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm using WDUC's answer wrong, but I don't get the right results with that method, as I wrote in my response to his answer. I have a different method that is conceptually the same as the thought experiment that I mentioned -- that is, if you put your prize image into an array once, and each of the other 3 images 8 times, then you would pick the prize image 8 times less often than any of the others. To implement this though, you can just have the random number generator pick from a set of numbers that would be equal to that hypothetical array's count (25 in this case), but then use the modulus operator to get the correct indexes.

If you have an array with 4 images, the prize image being last, this method should pick that last index (3 in this case) 8 times less often than any of the other 3 (I'm passing 4 for numOfItems and 8 for probFactor for your example):

```
-(int)indexOfSelectionFromItems:(int) numOfItems timesLessPicked:(int) probFactor {
    int size = (numOfItems - 1) * probFactor + 1;
    int pick = arc4random_uniform(size);
    if (pick != size-1) {
        return (pick % (numOfItems - 1));
    }else{
        return numOfItems -1;
    }
}
```